# ESP8266 restart after the second request to the server (Exception 9)

Tags: exception, server, client, esp8266, restart

I am new to this community, and I look forward to your help with this issue.
I have communication between two `ESP8266` modules. One of these as a Server/Access-Point and the other as a Client. The configuration and connection between these two modules are satisfactory, and part of the communication as well. However, after the `Client` makes the first request (Begin and GET), and the `server` responds, for the second `Client/Server` request, the Client restarts with the next message or exception.

```
Exception (9):
epc1=0x40207204 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x0036006a depc=0x00000000
```

That is, the first request to the server's root is answered, but the second to `/data` causes the mentioned restart on the `Client`.

After reviewing the stack exception decoder, I find that the code (9) means 9: LoadStoreAlignmentCause `Load or store to an unaligned address.`

Then, I've tried different solutions for this issue

- erase all flash content
- http.end()
- change the macro delay() for delayMicroseconds()
- and a few more

But nothing works yet.

Please, help me with this issue. The codes of the server and Client are:

### The client:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#define LED_PIN 2

const char* ssid     = "Mi_Servidor";
const char* password = "";
const char* host = "http://192.168.4.1";
int counter=1, httpCode=0;

HTTPClient http;

void peticion (int httpCode){
  String mensaje;
  if(httpCode == 200) {
    mensaje = http.getString();
    Serial.println(mensaje);
    } 
    else {
      Serial.print("[HTTP] GET... failed, no connection or no HTTP server\n");
    }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Conectando a ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("WiFi conectada"); 
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
}

void loop(){
  counter++;
  int modulo=counter%2;

  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    }
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
  
    if(modulo==0) http.begin("192.168.4.1", 80);   //HTTp   
    else http.begin("192.168.4.1", 80, "/data");   //HTTp
    
    httpCode = http.GET();
        
    Serial.print("httpCode: ");  //JJ
    Serial.println(httpCode);  //JJ
    
    peticion(httpCode);
    delay(20);     
    }
  Serial.println("End Loop!");
}
```

### And the server:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define LED_PIN 2

void handle_datos();

const char WiFiClave[] = "";  //Sin clave
const char AP_Nombre[] = "Mi_Servidor";
int val;
String MiMessage = "Message to transmit:\n\r";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handle_data() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", MiMessage);
  delay(1000);
  }

void handle_root() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Mi_root");
  delay(1000);
  }

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP(AP_Nombre, WiFiClave); 
  server.on("/data", handle_data); 
  server.on("/", handle_root); 
  server.begin();

//  for (int i = 0; i <= 3999; i++) {
//    MiMessage.concat(String(i));
//    MiMessage.concat(";");
//  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(MiMessage); 

  Serial.println("\nServidor ready... ");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  delay(100);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `http.end()` or do not reuse the object (make it local)